# Socket.io not connecting between users from different networks

Tags: express, websocket, socket.io, webrtc, web-development-server

I have a an express socket.io app when I test it on localhost it worked fine and when I hosted the app on vps it worked fine but the problem here is it worked fine when the two users were on the same network(pc = Wi-Fi and phone = Wi-Fi) but when I switched the network on my phone after that it wouldn't connect. I have searched about this issue everywhere but I can't find and fix for it and the app is a video call app
*Note: the server is working fine without any errors

I tried some A.I suggestions but it didn't work

Comment: The server must be available for incoming TCP connections from the client.  It's not clear what kind of environment your server is in from the limited description in your  question, but perhaps it isn't able to receive incoming connections from the internet.  So, when you put your phone on the internet, then it can't contact the server.  If the server is at home, then that would be because of issues with a public IP address and/or home firewall.